# i just want to know how to split phone number list for sending bulk sms

Tags: php, html

I have this code. I want to know how to send sms on 2000 different phone number i need a split code for example i just paste list of phone with one click and send message to all phone number list

```
 <html>
        <title>
        </title>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <label>phone</label>
        <textarea name="phone"></textarea>
        <label>message</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

        </form>
 </body>
    </html>



<?php 

    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $ph = urlencode($phone);
    $me = urlencode($message);
    echo $ph;
    $api = "xxxxxx";

    $url = "https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=$api&to=$ph&text=$me";
    if(isset($_POST[submit])){
    echo file_get_contents("$url"); 

        }

    ?>
```

Comment: What do you want to know? How to split a string containing phone numbers or how to bulk sms based on a list of phone numbers?

Answer (score -1):

**Python Solution:**

I think the best solution here would be to get the python api for Clickatell from [here](https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/scripts/python-library/), you could then use python to separate the individual numbers from the list of phone numbers you have.

e.g. If the phone numbers are in csv check out the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) of python.

**Web Solution**

You can use the [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) in python to do the same.

Comment: actually i am a beginner in programming i dont no about python language will you please help me with php

Comment: If you could provide details on how your list of phone numbers is stored it would be helpful.

Comment: i have list or phone number like    923244110311,923244110311, i want to pass one by  one number to     $url = "https://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg?api_id=$api&to=$ph&text=$me";
 this function send all sms on one click